# Why does ssh/sshd on server try to access /home/<user>/.ssh after I moved my users home directory?

Tags: ssh, centos, selinux

I moved my users home directory with `usermod -m -d /path/to/new/home/username` which seems to have worked fine.

However, in my [moved] home directory I have the ".ssh" folder that is set up to allow me connecting from another host using public key authentication, without password. This (public key auth. without password) has worked fine when connecting from the "client" workstation, *before* I moved my home directory.

`man sshd` says that the `authorized_keys` file location is by default `~/.ssh/authorized_keys` and my `sshd_config` does not override it because it has no `AuthorizedKeysFile` directive set at all.

Whenever I connect to the host from my "client", it asks for password. It should not, it should just log me straight in, courtesy of public key auth. My suspicion is that `sshd` on the host still thinks my home directory is `/home/<user>`, or at worst, insists adding my username to some assumed prefix, which no longer is valid.

The interesting thing is that if I spawn another `sshd -de -p 23` and connect to the host on this port with `ssh -p 23 ...` (same command line as otherwise, just with `-p 23` added), it recognizes my new home directory path on the host and logs me straight in indeed.

I tried reloading and restarting `sshd` with `service sshd reload` and `service sshd restart`, and finally even rebooted the host. Nothing changed with regards to `sshd` asking me for password.

Where do I start debugging this? I am on CentOS 6.5 x86-64.

#### Update

I have now strong indication that this is SELinux related. Apparently, the security context on the new home directory is wrong, but that's pretty much all I have found out. SELinux was installed on the system without me being asked, and I know nothing about it (nor should I, since I did not touch it, but relied on `usermod -m -d ...` to do a job it was supposed to do).

Comment: What is the output of ``ls -alZ ~/.ssh`` (using the new home directory)?

Comment: @Jonas, its basically `drwx------. <username> <username> system_u:object_r:etc_t:s0` for `~/.ssh`, `~/.ssh/authorized_keys` and even `..` (i.e. `~/.ssh/..` which is `$HOME` or `~`). `authorized_keys` does not have execute bit set.

Comment: You can try running ``restorecon -Rv ~/.ssh`` and see whether that changes the context to something like ``ssh_home_t``.

Comment: @JonasWielicki No change. The problem is that even though when adding user, SELinux seems to "assist" `useradd` with assigning a proper security context to /home/<user> (the default initial location of my home directory), subsequent `usermod -m -d ...` appears to not have involved SELinux at all, as the "vanilla" sec. context for new home directory indicates. I think the security configuration/templates for SELinux are simply inconclusive, as they should also cover behavior of `usermod`. But I don't really know much about SELinux, even though I have now spent 15 minutes reading into it.

Comment: I mean `restorecon` leaves the context as it was, unchanged. Which figures, as I have never explicitly changed it in the first place.

Comment: ``restorecon`` is sometimes able to do surprising magic. Well, the correct fix is then to modify your SELinux configuration, so that restorecon produces the correct context.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One solution is to modify your SELinux configuration so that SELinux is aware of the context required in this context:

```
semanage fcontext -a -s unconfined_u -t ssh_home_t '/path/to/your/new/home/\.ssh(/.*)?'
```

This is inspired by the output of `semanage fcontext -l | grep ssh`, which on my system reveals that `/root` is also managed that way.

Note that I picked the `unconfined_u` SELinux user – if you intend to use a different one, e.g. if this home is for a service, it might be sensible to pick `system_u` instead.

Comment: I would probably want to also do a similar thing with the `.../new/home` itself, using something like `user_home_dir_t`? that's what another users home directory lists with `ls -laZ`.

Comment: that seems plausible. You can aggregate a possibly useful set of rules by running ``semanage fcontext -l | grep '^/root'``.

Comment: Thanks, I added the "rules", and did a full relabeling. Now ssh connects without the password. By the way, my `~/.ssh` is not labeled with type `ssh_home_t`, just `user_home_t` as is every other subdirectory in my `~`. But that is probably distro specific behavior. The `/root/.ssh` is `ssh_home_t` indeed, however. But not my users.

Comment: @amn It is indeed distro specific. On my Fedora boxes, ``~/.ssh`` is consistently labelled ``ssh_home_t``.